S3 Only User that only be accessed by other resources in my AWS environment
I've inherited a unique case here that is making me look to have an IAM user in AWS with access to my S3 buckets (via an access key).  But the catch is that I don't want any resource that isn't running in my AWS account to access it.  Ideally, what I want is something like:
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": "*",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "NotIpAddress": {
                "aws:SourceIp": [
                    "192.168.0.0/16",
                    "10.0.0.0/16"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}

But AWS doesn't let you set a sourceIp to a private address.  What I need is for a variety of resources to be able to access this S3 bucket, but these resources are only going to run in AWS.  I can't use roles in this scenario to avoid this either unfortunately.

Why can't you use IAM Roles? That is the correct method for handling this situation.

If you only want to grant permissions based on the VPC where the API call originates, you would need to use a VPC Endpoint and then create a aws:SourceVpc Condition. See: AWS global condition context keys - AWS Identity and Access Management. Please note that this only relates to a specific VPC, not your whole AWS Account.

Tried it with a sourceVPC on the user and I'm still only getting access denied when running a simple python script from an EC2 instance in the VPC.

Did you also create a VPC Endpoint for S3? That is required if you are going to use aws:SourceVpc.
